# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Update Product Names To Title Case](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/update-product-names-to-title-case)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Ordering Modules that both use sales_order_place_after observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6888/ordering-modules-that-both-use-sales-order-place-after-observer)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Manually update custom currency exchange rate](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/manually-update-custom-currency-exchange-rate)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Magento extension, make config available for email templates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/magento-extension-make-config-available-for-email-templates)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Magento Collection Loading Prematurely](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/magento-collection-loading-prematurely)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Cron Setup- schedules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/cron-setup-schedules)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Update quantity of products in cart to the max available if quantity entered is greater than](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/update-quantity-of-products-in-cart-to-the-max-available-if-quantity-entered-is)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How best to restore the javascript console in Chrome/ developer tools in dev environment?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6520/how-best-to-restore-the-javascript-console-in-chrome-developer-tools-in-dev-env)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [convert a Quote into an Invoice, and mark it as Paid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7161/convert-a-quote-into-an-invoice-and-mark-it-as-paid)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Multi-Store issues with loading some template files/skins](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6457/multi-store-issues-with-loading-some-template-files-skins)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

Comment: What does this mean? 90 more days in beta? or graduation? ...or nothing?